# How Can I ignore .DS_Store and ___MACOSX file while unzipping?

Tags: java, macos, zip4j

I have compressed file on MacOS and I came to know that while compressing file some junk file like .DS_Store and __MACOSX  added in the zip file. Unzipping is not happening properly from the below code. Is there way I can ignore this junk file while doing unzipping?

```
public static void unzip(@NonNull final String zipFilePath, @NonNull final String destDir) {
    try {

        new ZipFile(zipFilePath).extractAll(destDir);

        log.info("Unzip completed for zipFilePath:{}", zipFilePath);

    } catch (final Exception e) {

        throw ExceptionTranslator.translate(e, String.format("Unzip failed for %s ", zipFilePath));
    }
}
```

Comment: where does ZipFile come from?

Comment: Check [https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless](https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless), I made a tool for preventing .DS_Store.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this ?